# Convert a date 2013-11-05 to Tuesday, 5th November, 2013 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have had a look at [datejs](http://www.datejs.com), but I cant get it to output the correct format.

It outputs "Nov" instead of "November" and adds the time "00:00:00" onto the end of the conversion.

`Date.parse('2013-11-05')`   ***outputs Tue Nov 05 2013 00:00:00***

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Date.parse`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2) is not reliable in pre-ES5 or with formats outside a [simplified version of ISO8601](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15). In addition, [`Date.toDateString`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.3) is also implementation-dependent.

I prefer [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) because it's small, well-documented, and quite robust - plus, I dislike writing date [parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) and [formatting](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) by hand. Something [like this (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/75fDv/1/) ought to do the job:

```
var m = moment('2013-11-05')
var str = m.format('dddd, Do MMMM, YYYY')
```

(Moment.js also supports localization, if you're into that sort of thing.)

Comment: Cheers, I will take a look now!

Comment: @user10324902 Whoops, "do" was the wrong format specifier (it's ordinal day-of-week). I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, below function give  **outputs is Tuesday, 5th November, 2013**

```
                var dateStr='2013-11-05';                    

                var str = DateConvert(dateStr);
                window.alert(str);    

                  function DateConvert(dateStr){          

                    var d = new Date(dateStr);
                    var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                                 "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ][d.getMonth()];

                    var day = d.getDate();
                     var suffix = 'th';
                     switch (day) {
                         case 1:
                         case 21:
                         case 31:
                             suffix =  'st';                                
                         case 2:
                         case 22:
                             suffix = 'nd';                             
                         case 3:
                         case 23:                                
                             suffix = 'rd';
                       }                         


                     var DayName = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednessday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"][d.getDay()];                      

                     var str = DayName+', '+day+suffix+' '+ month+', '+ d.getFullYear();

                  return str;
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can do something like this

`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var date=  new Date(); 
 var _strsplit= date.toDateString().split(" ");

 var Dayname=_strsplit[0];

 var MonthName=_strsplit[1];

 var Day=_strsplit[2];

 var Year=_strsplit[3];

 switch(Dayname)
 {

  case "Mon":
        Dayname="Monday";
        break;
         case "Tue":
        Dayname="Tuesday";
        break;

         case "Wed":
        Dayname="Wednesday";
        break;
         case "Thr":
        Dayname="Thrusday";
        break;
   case "Fri":
        Dayname="Friday";
        break;
         case "Sat":
        Dayname="Saturday";
        break;
         case "Sun":
        Dayname="Sunday";
        break;

 }
 switch(MonthName)
 {

 case "Nov":
      MonthName="Novemeber";
      break;
```

//do same for month's

```
 }

 document.write(Dayname +" "+MonthName+" "+Day+" "+Year);



}); 
</script>`
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the given code probably it would help you.

```
<script type="javascript">
   var dateTime = new Date(); 
   alert(dateTime.toString());
</script>
```

Comment: [Date.toString/to???String](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.2) are all "implementation-dependent".